# How to randomly delete observations in particular columns in dataset in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have tried using this loop but it deletes the entire row but I want only a few observations to be deleted in selected columns and should replace the deleted observations with NA.

```
for i in range(len(Germannewdata)) : 
  np.random.seed(10)
  remove_n = 100
  drop_indices = np.random.choice(Germannewdata.index, remove_n, replace=False)
  Germannewdata.loc[drop_indices]='NA'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
colnames = [. . . ]
for i in range(len(Germannewdata)) : 
  np.random.seed(10)
  remove_n = 100
  drop_indices = np.random.choice(Germannewdata.index, remove_n, replace=False)
  Germannewdata.loc[drop_indices, colnames] = 'NA'
```